# Concatenate files in order with type

Tags: concatenation

I am trying to use this command:

```
type *.dump > total
```

in order to concatenate my .dump files into total.

However, the numbering of concatenation is wrong. For instance the files in order are:

cascade1.dump
cascade10.dump
cascade 11.dump

as opposed to 1, 2, 3, etc.

Can someone help me figure out the numbering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `sort` has a way to do [natural sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order), called `version sorting` in its case:

```
-V, --version-sort          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

So you can do the following:

```
$ ls foo*
foo0  foo1  foo10  foo11  foo12  foo13  foo14  
foo15  foo2  foo3  foo4  foo5  foo6  foo7  foo8  foo9

$ ls foo* | sort -V
foo0
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
foo5
foo6
foo7
foo8
foo9
foo10
foo11
foo12
foo13
foo14
foo15

$ ls foo* | sort -V | xargs cat > total
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
ls -rt *.dump | xargs cat > total
```

It orders the *.dump files by `time` before concatenation.